# How do I check for the existence of a conda package before installing in ansible?

Tags: ansible, devops, conda

In my Ansible playbook I am doing this to install pillow (using Conda):

```
- name: Install Pillow
  shell: conda list | grep -q -i pillow || conda install --yes -c conda-forge pillow
```

Two questions:

1. Why does this always fail the Idempotence test ?
2. What is a better way of doing this ?

Comment: can you check that it exists at a given file location? Looks like there are some Conda library plugins for Ansible, they'd be much better.

Comment: Where ? I did not find any. Official ones I mean.

Comment: Unofficial. Which is a good thing, the patch cycles in the main repo are insanely long. They are really easy to install.

Comment: Answer to 1 is to move the `conda list | grep -q -i pillow` logic into a `when`, but change to check for absence and not presence. Looks like tedder42 answered 2.

Comment: I suggest trying a conda module. https://github.com/UDST/ansible-conda

Comment: @smiller171 Thanks. I did. I am considering trying to add that into ansible core. Seems like a useful thing to add. The author has since moved on and will not be continuing any efforts on developing the module or in this case submitting it to be part of the core.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about conda to know where pillow would be installed to, but you could do something like this:

```
- name: Install Pillow
  shell: conda list | grep -q -i pillow || conda install --yes -c conda-forge pillow
  args:
    creates: /path/to/pillow/binary
```